# Error with Guard working on PostGIS

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgis, guard

I've setup PostGIS with my Rails app according to the following tutorial: http://www.daniel-azuma.com/blog/archives/69

When I try to run my tests with Guard, I get the following error: 
`Exception encountered: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  must be owner of relation spatial_ref_sys: ALTER TABLE "spatial_ref_sys" ENABLE TRIGGER ALL>`

I've changed to owner of the postgis schema to my "normal" database user.
I'm also using database cleaner with my tests.

The full backtrace is as follow:

> /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.1.18/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:155:in `exec'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.1.18/lib/patches/sql_patches.rb:155:in`async_exec'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:654:in `block in execute'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:280:in`block in log'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.7/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:275:in`log'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:653:in `execute'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:530:in`ensure in disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:530:in `disable_referential_integrity'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/active_record/truncation.rb:132:in`clean'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/base.rb:39:in `clean_with'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:62:in`block in clean_with'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:62:in `each'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/database_cleaner-0.8.0/lib/database_cleaner/configuration.rb:62:in`clean_with'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/Projects/sos_medecins/spec/spec_helper.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in`instance_eval'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in `run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:72:in`block in run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:72:in `each'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:72:in`run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:424:in `run_hook'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in`block in run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in`run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/test_framework/rspec.rb:11:in `run_tests'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:13:in`block in run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:21:in `block in initialize'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in`fork'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/forker.rb:18:in `initialize'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in`new'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/run_strategy/forking.rb:9:in `run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/spork-1.0.0rc3/lib/spork/server.rb:48:in`run'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1548:in `perform_without_block'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1508:in`perform'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1586:in `block (2 levels) in main_loop'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in`loop'
>   /Users/OyoKooN/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/1.9.1/drb/drb.rb:1582:in `block in main_loop'

Thanks.

Comment: did you figure this out? im facing the same issue now. I tried adding an `except` clause to my DatabaseCleaner strategy ala `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation, {:except => %w[spatial_ref_sys]}` to no avail

Comment: It was a mistake on my side. I just forgot to run rake db:test:prepare.